# Magento2 checkout returns to cart instead of placing order

Tags: magento2

I want to add a "payonbill" feature for my shop so i am using the `checkmo` payment method to do so. I added a new module with this configuration:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <checkmo>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Checkmo</model>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <title>Check / Money order</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <group>offline</group>
                <payment_action>authorize_capture</payment_action>
            </checkmo>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

By doing so that payment status will migrate to processing and the payment action will be triggered for authorization. When doing so i am no longer able to even place an order on the shop for this method. The problem actually is there because of the payment_action. When i remove that it works again.

Is there a way to handle this scenario? When someone can pay on bill i would like to trigger the event `sales_order_invoice_pay` as well and continue the flow.

Best
Pim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by actually removing the stuff i previously did and by implementing this module:

https://github.com/dominicwatts/autoinvoice

The actual problem was that all was working fine but in the end for the offline payment the invoice is generated when booking it inside admin. Bypassing the status won't generate the invoice for you.